# Wordpress Images not showing up after migration - no 403 Forbidden

Tags: wordpress, amazon-ec2, bitnami

I migrated a Wordpress Site to a new EC2 instance (running bitnami) … everything seems to work generally but I might have a weird user rights problem or file permission problem as the Wordpress Backend (Media) always tells me

The problem is, that in some cases images are not showing on the site, on the old server they did. If I inspect the template with the images I can clearly see that the path checks out in the inspector and also the Console does not give me a 403 for the image or anything. It is as if they are simply not showing. I guess this is related to the same problem with the `/uploads` folder.

> Upload folder is not writable. Export and file upload features will
>   not be functional.

I have the rights for `/uploads` to `755` and contents and subfolder of `/uploads` to 644

Any idea what could cause this?

It also seems wordpress can't write the .htaccess file, it also seems to be not writable.

*My ssh user would be `bitnami`*

Comment: What procedure did you use for migrating wp content files?

Comment: I simply downoaded them to the desktop and moved them back up to the new server.

Comment: Two weeks ago I face the same issue, I fixed it but don't remember what actual procedure was that. Possibly I did >> 1. zip the folder, upload it, unzip it in new server, 2 > export database from PHPMyAdmin & import again. For my case issue was for the backup plugin. the plugin was to make a back up not for migration work.

Answer (score 0):

Bitnami Engineer here, you are probably running into a permissions problem. You can reset the permissions by running these commands

```
sudo chown -R bitnami:daemon /opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs
sudo find /opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs -type d -exec chmod 775 {}\;
sudo find /opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs -type f -exec chmod 664 {}\;
sudo chmod 640 /opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs/wp-config.php
```

You can find more information in this video tutorial

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nKfle7O0vN8&list=PLGgVZHi3XQNn4x0DU7Qj1r_inej3xEUda